# How to access a Javascript variable from Table data in HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-table

I have the following Javascript and want to access the "selection" variable in my HTML's td which already has an id

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
function getSelected() {
    if(window.getSelection) { return window.getSelection(); }
    else if(document.getSelection) { return document.getSelection(); }
    else {
            var selection = document.selection && document.selection.createRange();
            if(selection.text) { return selection.text; }
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content-area').mouseup(function() {
            var selection = getSelected();
            if(selection && (selection = new String(selection).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''))) {
            alert('Sending the following text to the server via AJAX: ' + selection);
                    $.ajax({
                            type: 'post',
                            url: 'calculate.php',
                            data: 'selection=' + encodeURI(selection)
                    });
            }
  });
});
</script>
```

The place I want to access "selection" variable is the html's td as follows,

```
<td>
<input type="button" id="optionone" name="optionone" onclick="sendrequest(selection , <?php echo $r ?>);" value="Positive"/>
</td>
```

I tried using id(content-area) but of no help. Please help.

Comment: you want to get the value attribute of the id="optionone" input?

Comment: You did not add PHP tag in your question.

Comment: Stu: No, I want to access the value of the variable "selection" in td and pass it to 'sendrequest' JS function. Help

Answer (score 0):

You can reach table items like that.

```
 var ptr = $("#tableid").find("#optionone"); // or .find("tr:first");
    ptr.find("#optionone).remove();  // or ("tr:first").remove();
```

refer to this comment:

Stu: No, I want to access the value of the variable "selection" in td and pass it to 'sendrequest' JS function. Help –  @mario23

Answer (score 0):

ok so you need the selection variable in  your onClick. I have a suggestion for this :

In your dom :

`<input type="hidden" id="hidden_optionone" value='<?php echo $r ?>'>`

why don't you write a click for the input as :

```
$("#optionone").click(function() {
  var php_val = $("#hidden_optionone").val();
  //$("body").data("get_selection") equals selection   
  sendrequest($("body").data("get_selection") , php_val);
});
```

and  finally

```
function getSelected() {
  if(window.getSelection) { return window.getSelection(); }
  else if(document.getSelection) { return document.getSelection(); }
    else {
        var selection = document.selection && document.selection.createRange();
        // THIS IS WHAT IS NEEDED
        $("body").data("get_selection",selection);
        if(selection.text) { return selection.text; }
        return false;
  }
  return false;
```

}

Comment: I've tried your soln but it is not working. Can you pl suggest a simple soln/fix?

Comment: @mario23...I have edited my answer at two places in the $("body") lines